# Contain Child div within Parent without setting a height on the child

Tags: html, css

Here is a code sample of my query.

```css
div.parent {
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #AAA;
  width: 20em;
  height: 12em;
  overflow: hidden;
}
div.child {
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="buffer">
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, quot dicam sit eu, dignissim complectitur ne per. Et per dico fabellas, cum oratio torquatos definitionem id. Ludus omnesque complectitur mea no. Quot corrumpit patrioque in eos, nec et aeterno vidisse numquam. Ad tollit verear eam. Errem maiorum nusquam te qui, ex recusabo abhorreant vim ipsum dolor sit amet, quot dicam sit eu, dignissim complectitur ne per. Et per dico fabellas, cum oratio torquatos definitionem id. Ludus omnesque complectitur mea no. Quot corrumpit patrioque in eos, nec et aeterno vidisse numquam. Ad tollit verear eam. Errem maiorum nusquam te qui, ex recusabo abhorreant vim ipsum dolor sit amet, quot dicam sit eu, dignissim complectitur ne per. Et per dico fabellas, cum oratio torquatos definitionem id. Ludus omnesque complectitur mea no. Quot corrumpit patrioque in eos, nec et aeterno vidisse numquam. Ad tollit verear eam. Errem maiorum nusquam te qui, ex recusabo abhorreant vim</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

### Description

A brief description, The parent has overflow hidden and child is expected to be contained within the parent but when it reaches the end child is expected to be scrollable. [**Edit**: I do not wish to make the parent overflow-auto because there may be some content above the child which is preferably not hidden when the user scrolls]

### What I've seen so far

Most solutions for this is to pre-set the height of the child, like this (http://jsfiddle.net/ad9q216L/3/), I've also seen some suggestions of repositioning the child using relative position on the parent and absolute position on the child like this (http://jsfiddle.net/ad9q216L/4/).

### My question

My question is this, is there any alternative solution where I do not have to set the height or position of the child yet make the child scrollable when the parent has overflow hidden with only css?

Comment: Why does the overflow on the parent need to be hidden?

Comment: How heigh is the child element in relation to its parent? Can you set it to `height: 100%`,  like [in this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/pjm874zu/). What's in `buffer`?

Comment: @j08691, I am sorry for not mentioning that, if the overflow hidden is not set on the patent, the child just runs over

Comment: @insertusernamehere the buffer could have any content which has its own height hence, in the document, pushing down the child. Also I would like to know if that can be achieved without setting heights on the child as the buffer height is not certain

Comment: But if you set the overflow on the parent to auto instead of hidden, don't you get what you want without setting the height on the child? http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/ad9q216L/6/

Comment: @j08691, however I am hoping to make only the child scrollable because if not, then the buffer would go out of view when the user scrolls the parent.

Comment: I'm afraid there's no CSS only solution. But with a little help from JavaScript, you could solve it like [here](http://jsfiddle.net/zg47jrx1/)

Comment: @insertusernamehere, I do not wish to use a JS patch as far as possible, however, you have answered my question, I only asked if there was a pure CSS solution, I guess not. Could you please post your comment as an answer that I can mark it as selected :)

Answer (score 0):

I think max-height: 100% will do the job

```css
div.parent {
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #AAA;
  width: 20em;
  height: 12em;
  overflow: hidden;
}
div.child {
  overflow: auto;
  max-height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="buffer">
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, quot dicam sit eu, dignissim complectitur ne per. Et per dico fabellas, cum oratio torquatos definitionem id. Ludus omnesque complectitur mea no. Quot corrumpit patrioque in eos, nec et aeterno vidisse numquam. Ad tollit verear eam. Errem maiorum nusquam te qui, ex recusabo abhorreant vim ipsum dolor sit amet, quot dicam sit eu, dignissim complectitur ne per. Et per dico fabellas, cum oratio torquatos definitionem id. Ludus omnesque complectitur mea no. Quot corrumpit patrioque in eos, nec et aeterno vidisse numquam. Ad tollit verear eam. Errem maiorum nusquam te qui, ex recusabo abhorreant vim ipsum dolor sit amet, quot dicam sit eu, dignissim complectitur ne per. Et per dico fabellas, cum oratio torquatos definitionem id. Ludus omnesque complectitur mea no. Quot corrumpit patrioque in eos, nec et aeterno vidisse numquam. Ad tollit verear eam. Errem maiorum nusquam te qui, ex recusabo abhorreant vim</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I understand but I am looking for a solution without setting heights. :(

Comment: it is not height. it is max-height ;-)

Comment: What you are describing is exactly what max-height:100% means. Grow in height till reaching the parent height. Why can't you use that?